# How to deploy war file to nexus using gulp? (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, gulp, war, web-deployment, nexus

I have a working Angular app and created a gulpfile to wrap my dist folder into a war file that is ready for deployment. However, the next step is to write a script to write the war file to Nexus Repository. How can I achieve this using gulp? I did some research and there is a tool you can use (nexus-deployer). You can use it to write something like this:

```
    var deployer = require('nexus-deployer');


    gulp.task('deploy:artifacts', ['artifacts:generate'], 
    function(callback) {

    var snapshot = {
    groupId: 'nexus-deployer',
    artifactId: 'nexus-deployer',
    version: '1.2-SNAPSHOT',
    packaging: 'zip',
    auth: {
        username:'admin',
        password:'admin123'
    },
    pomDir: 'build/pom',
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots',
    artifact: 'build/nexus-deployer.zip',
    noproxy: 'localhost',
    cwd: '',
    quiet: false,
    insecure: true
    };

    deployer.deploy(snapshot, callback);

    });
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to use this tool since it is coming from an external source. Is there any other way I can achieve this without using a package/tool?

Thank you for your help.